# Google App engine memcached design

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to memcache of GAE and I need a help in this.
Basically, I have a datastore which exceeded the Datastore Read Operations limit because of the fact that I didn't use memcache. My datastore has minimal writes but many reads and every time there's a write, it should be available for the read. Since, the site is up and I need a quick resolution for it so I need a design help in this. So the thing is, whenever there's a write in the datastore the new entry should get memcached. One more thing I would like to know that how the datastore can be replicated to the memcache. In parallel, I am working on it but since the site is up I am asking it here without any code in hand.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Java code looks like this:

```
        MemcacheService memcache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
        if(memcache.contains("LocationInfo"))
        {
            JSONArray js = new JSONArray((String)memcache.get("LocationInfo"));
            result = new ArrayList<LocationInfo>();

            for(int i = 0; i < js.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jso = (JSONObject)js.get(i);
                LocationInfo loc = new LocationInfo(jso);
                result.add(loc);
            }
        }
        else
        {
           q1= pm.newQuery(LocationInfo.class);
           q1.setFilter(filter);
           result = (List<LocationInfo>)q1.execute();
           JSONArray js = new JSONArray();
            for(LocationInfo loc : result)
            {
                js.put(loc.toJSON());
            }
            memcache.put("LocationInfo", js.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import memcache

def top_arts(update = False):
  key = 'top'

  #Getting arts from memcache
  arts = memcache.get(key)
  #Check if key is defined in memcache
  #or an update has been invoked
  if update or not arts:

      #Querying the Google Data store using GQL
      arts = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * from Art ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10')
      memcache.set(key, arts)

  return arts
```

You can use the same function for reading from memcache and then writing data into 
memcache

Eg:

for reading from memcache:-

```
 arts = top_arts()
```

when writing into database:-

```
#write your entry in database
<some database code>
#update memcache with this new entry
top_arts(update=True)
```

Comment: basically, I am using Java but it would not be much different. I will try it out.

Comment: In java, it doesn't seem to be simple. I want the datastore query results which are JDO objects to be memcached but I am not able to do serialization on that. Any suggestion on that?